# Spring Security asking authentication issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My basic spring security with in-memory auth is asking for credentials even after logging in to access intercept-URL . My Spring Config as follows

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WOW-PORTAL</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DailyStatusReport</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DailyStatusReport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

DailyStatusReport-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="org.WOW.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean name="TestExecutionReport" class="MasterCraft.src.testReport.TestExecutionReport"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

and my java config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                    .and()
                    .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "FOO");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login.do")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .usernameParameter("custom_username")
                    .passwordParameter("custom_password")
                    .failureUrl("/login.do?error=true")

                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout.do").logoutSuccessUrl("/login.do?logout=true")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/reports/*.do").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/schedule/*").hasAnyAuthority("FOO")
                    .anyRequest().anonymous();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="reports/addCoq",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddCOQScreen(){
        return "projectCOQ";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogincreen(){
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getCoq",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddCOQReportScreen(){
        return "COQReport";
    }
```

After login if i go to any intercept URL , i'm prompted with login page again

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<style>
.googleimage {
    margin: -15px -16px 1px -3px;
}
.userIcon {
float : right !important
}
</style>
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
   <li> <a target="_blank" href="#"class="googleimage">
        </a></li>
   <!-- <li> <img src="images/headerImages/cam.png"></li>
   <li><img src="images/headerImages/player.png"></li> -->
   <sec:authorize access="authenticated" var="authenticated"/>
    <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${authenticated}">
      <li>
       <p class="navbar-text">
        Welcome
        <sec:authentication property="name"/>
        <a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>
       </p>
       <form id="logout-form" action="<c:url value="/logout"/>" method="post">
        <sec:csrfInput/>
       </form>
      </li> 
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
     <a href="<spring:url value="/login.do"/>">Sign In</a>
      <li  class = "userIcon"><img src="images/headerImages/Account and Control.gif"></li>   
     </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Even the Welcome User is not coming in header..

Views
[image]

Comment: Why? choose one: xml or java config.

Comment: Did your jsps render at all?

Comment: You did not add the security config class in your `web.xml`

Comment: Rename your `DailyStatus-servlet.xml` to `DailyStatusReport-servlet.xml`. Since spring MVC looks for a file named `[servlet-name]-servlet.xml` in the WEB-INF directory of your web application(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet)

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#delegating-filter-proxy

Comment: You did not add your project structure, though. Describe, what your project looks like, where is your `web.xml`, `views`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix these two style of configurations. Choose one and stick with that choice. For example, you can use this java config instead:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ROLE_USER")
                    .and()
                    .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_FOO");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login.do")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                    .usernameParameter("custom_username")
                    .passwordParameter("custom_password")
                    .failureUrl("/login.do?error=true")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/reports/*").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .antMatchers("/schedule/*").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_FOO")
                    .anyRequest().anonymous();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching, still issue is there. if i go to /reports/* after successful login,  login page is prompted again

Comment: any ideas or suggestion

Comment: Add more details about your project structure, views, configs etc